# Code analysis: CA1303: Suppress Do not pass literals as localized parameters warning at application level

Tags: code-analysis

CA1303  Do not pass literals as localized parameters

Method `BlankQuestionnaireViewModel.QuestionnaireNames.get()` passes a literal string as parameter `value` of a call to `SelectListItem.Text.set(string)`. Retrieve the following string(s) from a resource table instead: "Core Questionnaires:".

I am getting this warning when i run the code analysis. i can suppress this warning in global suppression class and apply attribute over the method to avoid the warning.

Now, here i dont want to use this method, where i need to add attribute in all the classes because i have many warning and i want to suppress this at application level somewhere in web.config or anywhere, where i change at one place and should affect at all places and warning get suppressed.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To ignore a warning globally:

1. Create a new rule set (File menu > New > File... > Code Analysis Rule Set)
2. Configure the new rule set to ignore the warning (CA1303 in your case).
3. Select the new rule set in the project properties Code Analysis tab.

Answer (score -5):

If you want to fix this warning you can use below way to pass/get literals

```
    private static string FunctionNameToString(string FunctionName)
    {

        switch (FunctionName)
        {
            case "CoreQ":
                return "Core Questionnaires";
```